# HTML page won't validate

Tags: css, html, validation

Can somebody explain why this HTML document won't validate as HTML5 (using http://validator.w3.org/)? I get three errors:

1. Line 1, Column 33: Element head is missing a required instance of child element title.
2. Line 2, Column 16: Stray start tag html.
3. Line 2, Column 16: Cannot recover after last error. Any further errors will be ignored.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> //Random comment
<html lang="sv"> //Random comment
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" /> //Random comment
  <title>Startsida - Läxhjälpen</title> //Random comment
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <link href="laxhjalpen.css" rel="stylesheet" /> //Random comment
</head>
<body class="startpage"> //Random comment
  <header> //Random comment
  <div class="hwrap"> //Random comment
    <a href="./"><img class="logo" alt="Startsidan" src="./Images/laxlogo.png" /></a> //Random     comment
    <h1>Läxhjälpen</h1> //Random comment
  </div>
   <p class="tagline">Vi hjälper dig att förstå!</p> //Random comment
 </header>
  //Random comment
<section class="menu"> //Random comment
  <h2><a href="om-oss.html">Om oss <span style="color:blue;">&#x3020;</span></a></h2>
  <p>Man måste inte vara plugghäst för att kunna plugga. Vi själva är exempel på det.</p>
</section>
<section class="menu"> //Random comment
  <h2><a href="arbeten.html">Vad vi gör <span style="color:grey;">&#x2318;</span></a></h2>
  <p>Vi hjälper dig att plugga alla ämnen i skolan och förbereda dig för prov på bästa möjliga     sätt.</p>
</section>
<section class="menu"> //Random comment
  <h2><a href="blog.php">Blogg &#x272A;</a></h2>
  <p>Ta del av andra människors erfarenheter med vår tjänst.</p>
</section>
<section class="menu"> //Random comment
  <h2><a href="contact.php">Kontakt &#x260E;</a></h2>
  <p>Kontaktformulär, telefonnummer och adresser för att kontakta oss.</p>
</section>
  <footer>
    <small>&copy; Måns Nilsson AB</small> //Random comment
  </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Um, what's with all the `//Random comment`s?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`//Random comment` is not a comment in HTML. It is text content. Since such content is only allowed in the body (and the title), this generates an html element containing a head element (without a title) and a body element.

(Note that while html, head and body *elements* are required, the start and end *tags* for those elements are optional. The start and end tags for the title element are mandatory which is why the text ends up in the body and not the title)

```
<!-- This is an HTML comment -->
```

Comment: That fixed most of the problems. However, the validator now says "Bad value X-UA-Compatible for attribute http-equiv on element meta." for the "<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />" line.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using `<!--Random comment-->` **INSTEAD** of  `//Random Comment`

HTML comments =

`//` This is usually used within PHP or JQuery to comment out A LINE